# How to draw circumsphere of a tetrahedron unknowing center of sphere?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw a sphere passing through four points `A, B, C, D` of a tetrahedron `ABCD`. In this code, I have center of sphere is `(0,0,0` and radius of sphere is `a*sqrt(3)`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
 \begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{55}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a=3;}]
        \path
        (a,a,a) coordinate (B)
        (a,-a,-a) coordinate (D)
        (-a,a,-a) coordinate (C)
        (-a,-a,a) coordinate (A);
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) (A) -- (C) (A) -- (D) (B) -- (C) -- (D) (D) -- (B);
 \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={90:$A$}] at (A) {};
 \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={60:$B$}] at (B) {};
 \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={-90:$C$}] at (C) {};
 \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={90:$D$}] at (D) {};
 \draw[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle [radius = a*sqrt(3)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I have not coordinates of the center of sphere, how can I construct the center and draw sphere?

Comment: You can compute the center and radius given the corners.  4 quadratic equations, 4 unknowns (x,y,z coordinates for the center plus the radius).

Comment: Your sphere and coords are correct, this is an issue of the picture's perspective.

Comment: The center will also lie at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors (planes) of each of the edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can construct Based on John Kormylo, "The center will also lie at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors (planes) of each of the edges." In this code, the center will also lie at the intersection of the perpendicular  of each of the faces and passing through center of circumcircle of each of the faces.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=butt,line join=round,3d/install view={phi=235,theta=70,psi=60},declare function={a=3;}]
        \path
        (a,a,a) coordinate (B)
        (a,-a,-a) coordinate (D)
        (-a,a,-a) coordinate (C)
        (-a,-a,a) coordinate (A);
\path[3d/circumcircle center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)}}] coordinate (X); 
\path[3d/circumcircle center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(D)}}] coordinate (Y); 
    \path[overlay,3d coordinate={(myn1)=(A)-(B)x(A)-(C)},
    3d coordinate={(myn2)=(D)-(A)x(D)-(B)}];
    \path[3d/line with direction={(myn1) through (X) named d1},
    3d/line with direction={(myn2) through (Y) named d2}];  
    \path[3d/intersection of={d1 with d2}] coordinate (T);  
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myR}{sqrt(TD("(T)-(A)o(T)-(A)"))} ;  
    \draw[3d/screen coords] (T) circle[radius=\myR]; 
        \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) (A) -- (C) (A) -- (D) (B) -- (C) -- (D) (D) -- (B);
    \path foreach \p/\g in {B/90,C/-90,A/90,D/0,T/0}
        { (\p) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=\g:{{$\p$}}]{}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

With`3dtools`, we can use

```
\path[3d/circumsphere center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)},D={(D)}}] coordinate (I);
```

then, I is center of the sphere.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=butt,line join=round,
    3d/install view={phi=235,theta=70,psi=60},declare function={a=3;}]
    \path
    (a,a,a) coordinate (B)
    (a,-a,-a) coordinate (D)
    (-a,a,-a) coordinate (C)
    (-a,-a,a) coordinate (A);
    \path[3d/circumsphere center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)},D={(D)}}]
    coordinate (I); 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myR}{sqrt(TD("(I)-(A)o(I)-(A)"))} ;  
    \draw[3d/screen coords] (I) circle[radius=\myR]; 
    \path foreach \p/\g in {B/90,C/-90,A/90,D/0,I/0}
    { (\p) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=\g:{{$\p$}}]{}};
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) (A) -- (C) (A) -- (D) (B) -- (C) -- (D) (D) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(It is a long comment, not an answer)* Last year, due to low accuracy of TikZ and its limitation for 3D figures, I wrote a plain Asymptote module for both 2D and 3D, named it `ESgeometry.asy`. Instead of using geometric constructions, it concentrated on using `barycentric coordinates` (`signed area`, `signed length`) and avaiable `dot`, `cross products`. Of course it included usual commands such as `incenter`, `inradius`, `circumcenter`, `circumradius`, .... I minimalized the number of commands by using only 2 main one: `ESpoint` and `ESlength`.

```
triple O=ESpoint("circumcenter",A,B,C,D);
real R=ESlength("circumradius",A,B,C,D);
```

The code has not been cleaned yet. I am going to do it soon.

[image]

```
// a part of ESgeometry.asy (for both 2D and 3D)
triple barycentric(triple A, triple B=(0,0,0), triple C=(0,0,0), triple D=(0,0,0), real a=1, real b=0, real c=0,real d=0){
return (a*A+b*B+c*C+d*D)/(a+b+c+d);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compute signed area in 3D
real SignedArea(triple A, triple B, triple C){
return sgn(dot(cross(A,B),C))*abs(cross(B-A,C-A))/2;
}
// Compute (positive) area in 3D
real Area(triple A, triple B, triple C){
return abs(cross(B-A,C-A))/2;
}
triple ESpoint(string name="", triple A, triple B, triple C, triple D){
if (name=="circumcenter") {
triple O1=(abs(A-D))^2*cross(B-D,C-D);
triple O2=(abs(B-D))^2*cross(C-D,A-D);
triple O3=(abs(C-D))^2*cross(A-D,B-D);
real V=dot(A-D,cross(B-D,C-D));
return D+(O1+O2+O3)/(2*V);
}
else if (name=="incenter") {return barycentric(A,B,C,D,Area(B,C,D),Area(C,D,A),Area(D,A,B),Area(A,B,C));}
else if (name=="centroid") {return barycentric(A,B,C,D,1,1,1,1);}
else return (0,0,0);
}
triple ESpoint(string name="", triple A, triple B, triple C){
real a=abs(B-C), b=abs(C-A), c=abs(A-B);
if (name=="footbisector") {return barycentric(A,B,C,0,b,c);}
else if (name=="footaltitude") {return barycentric(A,B,C,0,1/(a^2+c^2-b^2),1/(a^2+b^2-c^2));}
else if (name=="incenter") {return barycentric(A,B,C,a,b,c);}
else if (name=="centroid") {return barycentric(A,B,C,1,1,1);}
else return (0,0,0);
}
///////////////////////////

unitsize(1cm);
import three;
import solids;  // only for better sphere, Circle
triple B=(0,0,0), A=(5,-.5,2), C=(1,3.5,3), D=(1,1,6);
draw(A--B--C--cycle^^D--A^^D--B^^D--C);
label("$A$",A,plain.W);
label("$B$",B,plain.S);
label("$C$",C,plain.E);
label("$D$",D,plain.N);
triple I=ESpoint("incenter",A,B,C,D); dot(I,red);
triple Id=ESpoint("incenter",A,B,C); dot(Id,red);
triple I1=ESpoint("footbisector",A,B,C); dot(I1); draw(A--I1);
triple I2=ESpoint("footaltitude",Id,B,C); dot(I2); draw(Id--I2);
draw(Circle(Id,abs(Id-I2),normal=cross(A-B,A-C)));
real r=abs(I-(I+reflect(A,B,C)*I)/2);
revolution b=sphere(I,r);
draw(surface(b),yellow+opacity(.5));

// the foot of different bisectors
triple Fa=ESpoint("bisectorfoot",A,B,C); dot(Fa,red);
triple Fd=ESpoint("bisectorfoot",D,B,C); dot(Fd,blue);

triple circumcenter(triple A, triple B, triple C, triple D){
triple O1=(abs(A-D))^2*cross(B-D,C-D);
triple O2=(abs(B-D))^2*cross(C-D,A-D);
triple O3=(abs(C-D))^2*cross(A-D,B-D);
real V=dot(A-D,cross(B-D,C-D));
return D+(O1+O2+O3)/(2*V);
}
triple O=ESpoint("circumcenter",A,B,C,D);
revolution Oabcd=sphere(O,abs(O-D));
draw(surface(Oabcd),green+opacity(.3));
dot(A^^B^^C^^D,red);
triple M=barycentric(A,C,.5,.5);
draw(D--M);
triple Mg=barycentric(A,C,D,1,1,1);
dot(Mg,orange);
triple Atest=barycentric(B,1/2); draw(D--Atest);
//draw(shift(D)*surface(plane(A,C)),blue);
//draw(surface(A--B--C--cycle),blue+opacity(.5));
//draw(surface(B--C--D--cycle),red+opacity(.5));
//draw(surface(C--D--A--cycle),magenta+opacity(.5));
```